# Explicitly declare the global namespace

Tags: c++

Is it possible to declare a variable or function in the global namespace from within another namespace?  Currently my code looks like this.

```
namespace test {
//do stuff
}

//declare global stuff

namespace test{
//continue stuff
}
```

The reason this question came up was because I am using an `#include` inside a namespace, but part of the included code needs to be in the global namespace. So I can not interrupt or code outside my namespace block.

So I would like:

```
namespace {// do stuff
//declare global stuff
//do more stuff
}
```

Now my code looks a bit like:

```
namespace test{
void majorfcn1();
Void majorfcn2();
#include "minorfunctions.h"
}
```

Which would be no problem if it just had functions. But in my case I threw some other includes in there that of course should be in the global space. So instead of cutting them out I was hoping I could keep them there and just surround them by a `namespace global{}` or something.

Comment: In general, don't do `#include`s within a namespace -- this completely defeats the abstraction of the header's contents (you need to know how it declares everything and what it declares in order to safely `#include` it in a namespace).

Comment: I find your first snippet fine.

Comment: Because I want to keep my class interface clean I put helper functions in a seperate file and included them.

Comment: @Quentin yes, but that is not an option if I inject code into a namespace block with include. Inside the file there is nothing to indicate that it is inside the namespace in the main module.

Comment: @jiggunjer oh, I did not understand that. Mmh, this gets tricky, and I'm afraid there's no real solution.

Comment: @jiggunjer Why do you need to `include` the helper functions inside a namespace?

Comment: Why do you need to put somethimg in a global namespace, when it's related to a class inside a namespace? Also, if those are helper functions, why not just put the include at the beginning of the file, before you open the namespace? An example of what you are trying to achieve would help.

Comment: @Daniel they are utility functions the client has access to. But they are lower level in the API so I don't want them cluttering up the header and obscuring the important functions. But putting the include outside the namespace (and using namespace inside the module) seems ugly from a design perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. I suggest you not `#include` from inside a namespace. That is not conventional C++ coding practices.

You said you would like:

```
namespace {// do stuff
//declare global stuff
//do more stuff
}
```

Then you can just do:

```
namespace {// do stuff
}

//declare global stuff

namespace {// do stuff
//do more stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you. If it were possible I could use the preprocessor to make a clean interface and keep my include files contained. Now I will need two include files or one in an ugly place...

Comment: I edited my answer to try and show how you may do this without preprocessing magic. Does this answer your question?